What kind of DB is best for frequent writes / rare reads?
It needs to:

Handle around 80,000 writes / second
Store billions of rows
Store them for many years
Consistency is a must
Reads are very rare
Data is currently stored in an RDBMS (I need to collect from many PostgreSQL with TimescaleDB databases, and store them in one central server) so It's structured
Data size can go up to 400-600 TB (if compressed, without it can be 10x as much) based on some estimation (but they would be separated as before the collection)
Once again, no data should be lost

Most likely data that was in separate DB before the collection will also be stored in separate DB after the collection, so this 80 000 writes, and the 400-600 TB size will be divided between many Databases, so It might not be as scary as it sounds.
